# how to redirect request for lost files to different server (nginx configuration)?

Tags: configuration, nginx

I want to redirect request for image to github repo, if image can't be found on server.
Where i made a mistake?

```
    location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ {
            try_files $uri /gitpipe =404;
    }

    location ~* /gitpipe$ {
            proxy_pass https://raw.github.com/Org/$arg_repo/master/$uri;
    }
```

---

I change configuration to next

```
location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ {
    try_files $uri /gitpipe =404;   
}

location = /gitpipe {
            proxy_pass http://websaints.net/rlog.php?save;
}
```

but result still the same. Nginx don't redirect request to static url http://websaints.net/rlog.php?save;
So problem not in $uri.

---

btw this configuration work, but it redirect to uri, not proxy and cache it

```
location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ {
    try_files $uri @redirect;
}

location @redirect {
            return 301 http://websaints.net/rlog.php?save&req=$request_uri;
}
```

hmmmm...

Comment: And why it doesn't work? Returning always with `404` or something else?

Comment: and no request to https://raw.github.com/ ever making. i test this wit h my server and acess log

Comment: can you give an example url what are you using for testing?

Comment: Yes, shure. This is it http://websaints.net/rlog.php — to view and http://websaints.net/rlog.php?save to write new request to log

Answer (score 1):

At first, you can easly change your `location` to:

```
location = /gitpipe {
```

because it means the same what `^/gitpipe$' but has the highest priority in nginx so such location will be always taken as first.

Next, you are trying to return files if their exist, so with url like:

```
http://your.domain.com/some_dir/another_dir/some_file.gif
```

which pass first `location` block you are trying to get filestarting from your `root` directive as :

```
root_directive/some_dir/another_dir/some_file.gif
```

if this file doesn't exist then you say to `try_files` directive that it should search in second `location` block and here you are proxy passing such url:

```
proxy_pass https://raw.github.com/Org/$arg_repo/master/$uri;
```

but for our example it will mean:

```
proxy_pass https://raw.github.com/Org/$arg_repo/master//root_directive/some_dir/another_dir/some_file.gif
```

where `$arg_repo` will be change will its value.

Is this explanation of what your directives do is exactly this what you had in mind?

**Here's how you can easly redirect to what you want:**

```
location ~ \.(jpg|png|gif) {
   try_files $uri /proxy$request_url =404;
}

location ^~ /proxy(.*) {
   proxy_pass https://your.proxy.domain/$1;
}
```

Comment: I got it! proxy pass can't include directory! only domain name.
proxy_pass http://websaints.net; — this work. https://frontender.info/test.jpg redirect request to http://websaints.net/test.jpg 
Now if I only understand how to add directories...